# Merging two Minecraft map's chunks, one with builds and another just the terrain

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a Minecraft map in worldpainter, exported it and got it on a server, then we built some mines in a small part of the map. However, we found that some parts of the map probably got corrupted and there were a lot of empty chunks.

I still have the unbuilt version of map and want to just add the missing chunks back to the map with builds, and MCEdit is giving me a lot of errors.

Is there any other way of doing it?

[image: this is how the missing chunk map look]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest - if your custom builds only occupy a relatively small volume; significantly smaller than the error chunks - to use [Litematica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica) to mark them and generate schematics of them in the corrupted world (and write down the coords of each area you make the litematic of), then make a copy of the 'pristine' custom world, substitute the server's world with it, verify it's fine this time (no chunk errors), then use litematica's "paste" function (after aligning the placements of the schematics to their original positions) to restore your builds.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

If what you are missing is in chunks, you could pull the chunk files from your unbuilt map. Dinnerbone created a web tool for you to calculate the coordinates to the chunks:

https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/

This isn’t always the easiest method, but it is the most rudimentary. You’ll just copy the chunk files from your unbuilt folder to your folder with missing chunks.

Edit- Actually, you could try copying all of your new chunks onto a copy of the unbuilt world. This should overwrite all of the chunks that a new version exists, and keep the remainders from the unbuilt world.

**Option 2:**

As long as your map uses Minecraft’s vanilla-normal blocks, you could drop the world into a spigot server, configure and use World Edit. World Edit has a restore feature that can pull blocks from a backup:

https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/snapshots/

Set your unbuilt world as a snapshot backup, then use world edit command inside the game to *restore* areas.